# How to authenticate XboxLive user in WebApi

Tags: c#, xbox-live

I have a working Xbox UWP app via the XboxLive Creators Program, which authenticates an XboxLiveUser using the SignInSilentlyAsync and SignInAsync methods demonstrated in Microsoft's documentation.

I would like my Xbox application to call my WebApi backend, and have that project authenticate the caller.  In other applications, I use OAuth and simply pass in the (previously authenticated) user's tokens, and the WebApi simply validates the token and returns unauthorized when it is not valid.   However, I'm not seeing how to do that when called from the Xbox code.

I have looked at OpenXbox (https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-csharp), and the XAL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/get-started/add-signin-code/getting-xsapi-to-sign-in).   Both of these seem to need an interactive UI to login the user, but from a WebApi context, an interactive login is not possible.

I feel I'm missing something obvious...  Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to do this authentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For **XAL** you need to be in a managed partner program as a pre-requisite (ID@Xbox). The Creators Program doesn't qualify for that.

[image: Screenshot from the XAL documentation]

For **OpenXbox** you may put your question to the developers at GitHub